# How could I get merchant account id of paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use the PayPal Adaptive Payments Payment API. I am trying to test the API with my own email address, but I get an error specifying the sender by email. I'm wondering how to determine my own account ID to try that way?

I'm referring to the account id here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/PaymentDetails_API_Operation/

I get the error: "The email address smithd98@gmail.com is invalid. It may not be registered in PayPal's system yet" when trying to pay by my email. When I log in with PayPal my email address is correct. My account is verified with a bank account, credit card, and debit card connected.

Comment: I want only Merchant Account ID from paypal without go [link](http://www.paypal.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your PayPal account ID by logging into your PayPal account and looking in your profile, or you can also get it via the [GetPalDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetPalDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).